# How to manage a music library in wordpress

Tags: media-library, sort

I need to make a music library which will primarily be sorted by artists. I'll need a database to hold all the music titles, artist, genre etc. I'll need some sort of backend language to manage the library when users are interacting with it. I'm kind of new creating this sort of website, I'm having trouble piecing all the pieces together for this, I've only managed static websites before.

I need guidance or advice on which technologies to use to make a standard music library which is primarily sorted by artist.

Comment: 1 : The first step to make a dynamic website is to list all objects that you need with the fields of theses objects. This step help you to prepare the database with a few rules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form. 2 : The second step is to list all functionalities like "display all artists", "show titles of an artist". 3 : The last step is to code everything. With WordPress it may exist plugins which do a big part of the work but I recommand you to learn PHP to custom the website as you want.

Comment: @mmm Thanks, this certainly puts things into perspective form me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom post type called `songs` or `albums`.

- Learn more about custom post type registration here:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
- More info on Post Type: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

You can register custom taxonomies in WordPress as well.

- Learn about taxonomies here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies
- Learn about taxonomy registration here:
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

You can then associate `songs` or `albums` with an `artist`. This can be achieved quite easily by using the two following tools.

- https://generatewp.com/post-type/
- https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

Adding the output to your `functions.php`.

If you want to query your new post type you can use `WP_Query`.

Read more on it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Simple tool to generate a WP_Query - https://generatewp.com/wp_query/